# Java on mac osx uses name like com.pro.MainFrame

Tags: java, macos

When you run Java GUI App on mac osx, The name of the application is the fully qualified classname of the main class. How can I change this to show something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier than easy!
Add this Java option on execution

```
-Xdock:name="Application Name"
```

For other aspects specific for Mac read [Oracle reference](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this by setting

```
System.setProperty( "com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Your App Name" );
```

before you construct your Frame class